# class diagram in OO programming with API

Tags: oop, class-design, class-diagram, application-design, object-oriented-analysis

- I am trying to create a class diagram for an application that I am
  trying to create within a given framework.
- This framework exposes
  its own custom API and some of the classes in my design is
  represented by the classes in the API.
- Some of these classes tend to
  get pretty complex, so I am faced with the question of how to
  represent these classes in my class diagram - or should I even
  attempt to do that.

To be more specific,

- My application moves artifacts from one server to another.
- The framework I am working on provides classes and methods to represent and communicate with the source and destination server.
- Now, I know that my class diagram needs to account for the
  representation of the server class and its functions, **but how can I
  do it in my class diagram**.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a package for your framework/custom API which contains the classes (from the custom API) you need to link to your own classes. Here's an example:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: That is a good idea. But I was wondering about the details that I need to put into the class diagram. Do you have any example of such a scenario/ illustration?

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please refer to the example. Thanks.

Comment: I use Enterprise Architect, but you can use Visio for the class diagram.